# touchevents in tableviews

Tags: iphone, ios

```
                              UIView 
              UITableView(T1)            UITableView(T2)
```

In T1 Am showing some tracks and in T2 am showing rows with buttons and labels. when we click on tracks(table rows) in T1 it has to generate one image on the top of the selected row, then we can move the generated image anywhere in screen and finally if we drop that image in T2 rows it has to fit into T2 row where it has dropped. Here am generating image when we click on the row in T1 and i can move that generated image anywhere in the screen but when i drop on to the T2 row it is not adding to T2 row.

How can we add that generated image in T2 row.

Any one can help with code or ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use only one tableview (grouped style) for this just set different cell identifier for your track and rows. Then get the cell for index on which image is dropped.

Comment: +----------------------------+
|A                           |
|+--------+   +------------+ |
||B       |   |C           | |
||        |   |            | |
|+--------+   |            | |
|             |            | |
|             +------------+ |
+----------------------------+  This is the UIView And two tables what i have. Here B(T1) and C(T2) in this i have to drag and drop. They must be two tables.]